# Сообщение об отключении/подключении устройства в jack-разъём, WinAPI

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Собственно..реально ли силами winapi? Или, может, что-то в реестре меняется, по этом сравнивать к примеру.

Comment: [Device Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370810(v=vs.85).aspx). Однако, это работает только в Vista и выше. У вас какая версия ОС?

Comment: Как бы то ни было, сейчас напишу рабочий пример для этой технологии.

Comment: win 7, 8.1 и 10
Три домашних ПК
Но приоритетная - 10

Comment: @Arhad с нетерпением жду!

Comment: @Arhad начал разбираться, но погряз в неясностях. Вот первые признаки, чего-то не подключили вроде, а что именно не ясно: Ошибка LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "_IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator" Ошибка LNK2001 неразрешенный внешний символ "_CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator" Класс и методы разделены по заголовочному и исходному файлу. Подключаю через #include заголовочный к главному файлу(main.cpp)

Comment: Проверьте в свойствах проекта, что у вас подключена библиотека `libole32.a` (либо `ole32.obj`, если у вас Visual Studio). Сам я проверял на MinGW-w64.

Comment: @Arhad странно, но студия(а у меня именно она) не находит данную статическую библиотеку

Comment: Прошу прощения, `Ole32.lib`. Это же библиотека, а не единичный объектный файл.

Comment: @Arhad увы, уже проверял - но без результатов всё

Comment: @Arhad проблему решил так:
const CLSID CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator);
 const IID IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator = __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator);
Определил перед вызовом CoCreateInstance

Но, запустив, программа просто уходит в ожидание, не реагируя на подключение/отключение наушников. Ещё проверю на другой системе конечно...

Comment: @Arhad сообщаю: а другом компьютере подключение наушников прекрасно ловится. Посоветуйте, куда можно ещё копать?
P.S.: компьютер, где не ловится подключение - ноутбук, и там комбинированный разъём. Возможно это играет роль

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться [MMDevice API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd316556(v=vs.85).aspx), добавленным в Windows Vista. Для этого необходимо последовательно выполнить следующие действия:

1. Объявить слушателя событий.
2. Передать его методу [`RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/dd371403(v=vs.85).aspx) перечислителя звуковых устройств. Разумеется, этот перечислитель сначала необходимо создать.
3. Обрабатывать поступающие события с тем расчётом, что методы слушателя будут вызываться в отдельном потоке.

Обратите внимание: если раньше подписка на события заключалась в обработке оконных сообщений, то сейчас, в мире COM, необходимо передавать указатель на экземпляр класса-слушателя.

Вот пример кода, обрабатывающего события активации/деактивации, подключения/отключения. К сожалению, Windows API не предоставляет возможности различать подключение и активацию, рапортуя лишь о готовности устройства.

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <initguid.h>
#include <Mmdeviceapi.h>
#include <Objbase.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>


// Базовая реализация, выводящая в консоль уведомления о втыкании/вытаскивании джека.
class JackStateNotificationClient : public IMMNotificationClient 
{
public:
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject);
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE AddRef();
    virtual ULONG STDMETHODCALLTYPE Release();

    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDefaultDeviceChanged
        (EDataFlow flow, ERole role, LPCWSTR pwstrDefaultDevice);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDeviceAdded(LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDeviceRemoved(LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnDeviceStateChanged
        (LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId, DWORD dwNewState);
    virtual HRESULT STDMETHODCALLTYPE OnPropertyValueChanged
        (LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId, const PROPERTYKEY key);
};

HRESULT JackStateNotificationClient::OnDefaultDeviceChanged(
    EDataFlow flow,
    ERole role,
    LPCWSTR pwstrDefaultDevice
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(flow);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(role);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pwstrDefaultDevice);

    // Смена устройства по умолчанию нам неинтересна
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT JackStateNotificationClient::QueryInterface(REFIID riid, void** ppvObject)
{
    // Наш объект не является полиморфным, это простой одноразовый перечислитель
    return ppvObject ? E_NOINTERFACE : E_POINTER;
}

ULONG JackStateNotificationClient::AddRef()
{
    // Наш объект статичен, а потому не нуждается в COM-овском методе подсчёта ссылок
    return 1;
}

ULONG JackStateNotificationClient::Release()
{
    // Наш объект статичен, а потому не нуждается в COM-овском методе подсчёта ссылок
    return 1;
}

HRESULT JackStateNotificationClient::OnDeviceAdded(LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId)
{
    // Устройство зарегистрировано
    std::wcout << pwstrDeviceId << L" was registered\n";
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT JackStateNotificationClient::OnDeviceRemoved(LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId)
{
    // Устройство разрегистрировано
    std::wcout << pwstrDeviceId <<L" was unregistered\n";
    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT JackStateNotificationClient::OnDeviceStateChanged(
    LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId,
    DWORD dwNewState
)
{
    switch(dwNewState)
    {
        case DEVICE_STATE_ACTIVE:
            // Устройство активировано через панель управления, либо подключен джек
            std::wcout << pwstrDeviceId << L" was enabled or plugged\n";
            break;

        case DEVICE_STATE_DISABLED:
            // Устройство деактивировано через панель управления
            std::wcout << pwstrDeviceId << L" was disabled\n";
            break;

        case DEVICE_STATE_UNPLUGGED:
            std::wcout << pwstrDeviceId << L" was unplugged\n";
            break;
    }

    return S_OK;
}

HRESULT JackStateNotificationClient::OnPropertyValueChanged(
    LPCWSTR pwstrDeviceId,
    const PROPERTYKEY key
)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(pwstrDeviceId);
    //UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(key);

    // Настройка устройства нас не интересует
    return S_OK;
}


int main()
{
    ::CoInitialize(NULL);

    IMMDeviceEnumerator* enumerator;
    HRESULT result = ::CoCreateInstance(
        /* rclsid       */ CLSID_MMDeviceEnumerator,
        /* pUnkOuter    */ NULL,
        /* dwClsContext */ CLSCTX_ALL,
        /* riid         */ IID_IMMDeviceEnumerator,
        /* ppv          */ (void**)&enumerator
    );
    if(result == S_OK)
    {
        JackStateNotificationClient listener;
        enumerator->RegisterEndpointNotificationCallback(&listener);

        // =========================

        // События будут приходить в другом потоке, так что можем спокойно делать
        // свои дела. Например, разбирать оконные сообщения. Ну или просто ждать,
        // как в этом примере.
        const HANDLE hFreezingEvent = CreateEvent(
            /* lpEventAttributes */ NULL,
            /* bManualReset      */ FALSE,
            /* bInitialState     */ FALSE,
            /* lpName            */ NULL
        );
        ::WaitForSingleObject(hFreezingEvent, INFINITE);

        // =========================

        enumerator->UnregisterEndpointNotificationCallback(&listener);
        enumerator->Release();

        ::CoUninitialize();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    else
    {
        std::wcout << (result == REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG
            ? "You need Windows Vista or newer\n" : "Unknown error\n");

        ::CoUninitialize();
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вечером буду разбираться и пробовать.
P.S: и всё же, как же огромная библиотека winapi...